# Eigenvalues of the product of one diagonal and one regular matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm reading a paper that makes the following claim that I don't understand.

Let $\Sigma, K\in\mathbb{R}^{n,n}$, where $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix with only non-negative real entries. Then the claim says that

$$\max_{i\in\{1,\cdots,n\}}Re(\lambda_i(K))\leq 0$$

implies

$$\max_{i\in\{1,\cdots,n\}}Re(\lambda_i(\Sigma K))\leq 0,$$

where $\lambda_i(\cdot)$ denotes the $i^{th}$ eigenvalue of the respective matrix. There are no other requirements to either $\Sigma$ or $K$ beyond the ones mentioned.

Does anybody know why this is true?

For reference, the paper claiming this is [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.03341) in equations (3.6) to (3.8).

Comment: I'm looking at the paper, but I don't see where $\Sigma$ is supposed to come into play

Comment: @Omnomnomnom $\Sigma$ is the diagonal matrix in equation (3.7). I renamed it for simplicity. Thank you very much for taking a look!

Comment: Any conditions on $K$? Also why are we taking real parts if everything is real?

Comment: @InertialObserver no conditions on $K$ in the paper :/

Comment: @InertialObserver the matrices are real, but their eigenvalues do not need to be.

Comment: @Alex I misread the diag part, thanks

Comment: @InertialObserver even if $K$ has real entries, its eigenvalues might be non-real

Comment: I agree I guess I just assumed we were working over the real field

Comment: @Alex if we know that $K + K^T$ (or $K + K^*$ in the complex entry case) has positive eigenvalues, then there's a nice trick that applies, I'm not sure if it works in general.

Comment: @Alex in any case, it might be helpful to consider the similar matrix
$$
\Sigma^{-1/2}(\Sigma K)\Sigma^{1/2} = \Sigma^{1/2} \, K \, \Sigma^{1/2} 
$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I'm afraid they assume only that the eigenvalues of $K$ have negative real parts, no other conditions. That's what drives me nuts. I'm trying to play around with your second suggestion, but haven't figured out yet how that might help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated, the result is not true. For instance take 
$$
K=\begin{bmatrix} 2&-5\\ 5&-10\end{bmatrix},\ \ \ \Sigma=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}. 
$$
The the eigenvalues of $K$ are negative, but $2$ is an eigenvalue of $\Sigma K$.

A small variation of the example, where $\Sigma$ is invertible, is to take
$$
\Sigma=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1/10\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then $\Sigma K$ has both eigenvalues with real part $+1/2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Would it be true if $\Sigma$ had full rank though?

Comment: And if $K$ also has full rank.

Comment: Edited. The $K$ in my example has rank two.